# how to disable/hidden a list element using Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Once my `eraser` is clicked, I want the `color` to hidden or shouldn't show its dropdown elements. I tried..here is my partial code.

```
   $('#chooseEraser').mousedown(function(e){
        curTool = "eraser";
        checkEraser = true;
        $('#color').remove();
    });
```

Here is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/priyaa2002/PyXsh/)

Comment: As of now, nothing happens if I press "Color" there... Was it meant to be like that ?

Comment: What's wrong with `$('#color').css("visibility","hidden");`?

Comment: @use hide() instead of .remove as it removes the html completly.

Comment: I see no element with an id of `chooseEraser` in your HTML.

Comment: As of now, after I click "eraser" ..I still see the "color" even after adding $('color).hide();

Comment: @siri -- even remove is not removing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried `$("#color").hide();` and it did work on your page.

Your code is just missing the # symbol.

Also, try using `jQuery` instead of just `$`: `jQuery("#color").hide();`. The `$` shortcut might not always be available (redefined in some scopes).

Comment: I didn't miss #..I see it there. Anyways its not working for me..I didn't understand

Comment: http://dragonfly.zymichost.com/Canvas/js/canvas6.js  is missing the # on line 111.

Comment: Nevermind.  Neat experiment that you're doing with the canvas element, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly understand your question and I don't think you're doing anything wrong in your code.  But just for clarification, there are a few ways that you can hide/disable elements using jQuery:

This will hide the element but the element will continue to take up space on the page:

```
$('#colorId').css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

This will hide the element and no longer occupy any space on the page:

```
$('#colorId').hide();
```

This will disable the element:

```
$('#colorId').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```